# Creating custom Symbol object

Tags: python, sympy

I am doing some symbolic calculations using Sympy, but I need to define some custom objects. The way I have been doing it so far is to take advantage of Sympy's Symbols by defining a new class

```py
class CustomSymbol(sym.Symbol):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.custom_attribute = True
```

this way I can reuse a lot of code. Still, I had to overwrite some of the functions and define a custom Add, Mul, Pow, etc...
Now, the problem is the following:

```py
from sympy import *

class CustomSymbol(Symbol):
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return CustomPow(self, other)

class CustomPow(Pow):
    pass

a = CustomSymbol('a')
x = a**2 * a**3
type(x)
```

this code returns that the type of `x` is Sympy's Pow, not CustomPow. And essentially is because, in the internal code, Sympy essentially computes `Pow(a, 2+3)`.
The fact that Sympy uses this approach instead of a much more flexible one like computing `a**(2+3)` and letting `a` decide how to manage exponentiation leads me to think that maybe there is an intended way to define custom symbols.

So, my question is: How should one approach the creation of a CustomSymbol class? Is there a workaround to the problem I wrote that does not require essentially rewriting the entire Sympy library?

Comment: You do not "**need** to define some custom objects". Take a step back and ask how to solve your original problem before asking how to make this work with custom objects. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: CustomPow ist empty.. except that it inherits Pow. So `x` is of type `CustomPow`, which is `Pow` (from `sympy`). You don't even have an __init__. I believe your confusion has little to do with `sympy`, it is more likely you might want to play around a bit with class definitions in Python in general... and I don't agree with the "XY" comment... your question looks very clear to me: you expected class of type `A` but saw `B`, that is a very well-posed and clearly very rational question. If others think there is a faster/better way to solve it, that's fine...

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, defining these custom objects is not a solution to any problem, is the problem itself. These custom objects are the base of the code I am working with, they have custom attributes and methods. Now I need to do symbolic manipulations on them. Do you have any suggestions on how to make symbolic manipulations on a custom object that is not how I phrase it in my OP?

Comment: @KingOtto, well the class is empty because this is a minimal reproducible example. Anyway, I don't understand why CustomPow being empty is a problem, if x is not an instance of CustomPow, then any extra functionality is lost anyway. Of course, I could add a __mul__ method (which I already have, btw) but to solve this problem I would essentially need to rewrite the entire sym.Mul class, which I want to avoid.

Comment: It is almost certainly a bad idea to make these custom objects. Whatever problem they seem to solve can be better solved some other way. I can't say exactly how because you don't give the reason for having them in the first place (hence my reference to XY problem),

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, well I don't know if the specific problem is really relevant here. The problem is what I have in my OP, I have a class representing an abstract mathematical object, with some attributes and methods (for simplicity I just showed a dummy attribute). Now I want to add symbolic manipulations to these objects.

Comment: Classes like `Pow` are not designed to be subclassed and nor is SymPy designed so that `__pow__` can be used to customise symbolic manipulation. The problem that you are asking about here is only the beginning of the problems that you will find if you continue down this path. I'm not going to answer your question about how to make the custom objects because I think that it is very likely a mistake to do so in the first place. No reason is given for wanting to do this so I cannot offer any alternative suggestion.